# how to force SSL _and_ remove www in one rule?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, no-www

I've got a ExpressionEngine site where I need to force SSL *and* remove the www. from the URL. I'm using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But I've just realised that if someone visits https://www.URLHERE.com they will not get the www's removed. Is there a way to both force SSL and remove WWWs in one rule (i.e. can I do an 'or' or something?) or will I have to make 2 rules, one to remove the WWW and one to force SSL?

Answer (score 2):

Have `OR` condition in your rule for both conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

// rest of your rules here...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can I just ask what the other changes are you've made? NE instead of QSA and your WWW check has a ?: at the start as well as a + instead of *

Comment: QSA is used only when you're modifying query string (not applicable here). `.+` instead of `.*` because domain name would definitely have more than 1 character after `www.` Also NE if for not encoding the resulting URL.

Comment: Hm, can I ask is there a way to test this on a non-https server? I'm trying to see if it works but I don't currently have access to https (apart from the live site). I tried changing the https in the third line to http but that causes a redirect loop :/

Comment: You can install XAMPP or MAMP packages locally and test it out.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and it causes a redirect loop. I'll add the rest of the htaccess above

Comment: Ok give me some time, I will test it locally and update in few minutes.

Comment: ok I tested and corrected my rule. Please check the edited answer.